# @babel/runtime vs babel-runtime

Tags: webpack, babeljs, yarnpkg

I'm trying to get all my JS/TS project dependencies up to date, and I see that `@babel/runtime` is the new way, while `babel-runtime` was the old way. I put `@babel/runtime` into my `package.json` (I end up with 7.8.4), but I still end up with `babel-runtime@6.26.0` because some of my dependencies need it.

Is there any way for me to prevent the old `babel-runtime` getting installed, and replace it with `@babel/runtime? Would that even work? I'm using yarn and webpack.

The reason I care is that `babel-runtime` pulls in old versions of `core-js` which is what I'm really trying to get rid of.